# How in template show button if object is empty?

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, django-1.10

Can someone say where I did mistake?

I have 2 models: Project and Purpose.

```
class Purpose(models.Model):
    code = models.UUIDField(_('Code'), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField(_('Text'))
    comments = models.ManyToManyField("Comment")
```

Every project has only one purpose. So in `project_detail` page I want to show `purpose_add` button only if that project dont have any other purpose object. Why I dont see button when there is no Purpose object with the same `project_code`?

**views.py:**

```
def project_detail(request, project_code):
 ***
 purpose_is_not_exist = Purpose.objects.exclude(project=project_code).exists()
 ***
```

**project_detail.html:**

```
{% if purpose_is_not_exist %}
   <button id="purpose-add-button"></button>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{% if not purpose_is_not_exist %}
```

You should negate the False bool.

Answer (score 2):

The confusion is caused by the variable name `purpose_is_not_exist`.

```
Purpose.objects.exclude(project=project_code).exists()
```

Above statement returns whether the `Purpose` object exists. You shall rename the variable to `purpose_exists` to avoid any confusion.

And, in the template when you want to add the button if it doesn't exist then negate the variable:

```
{% if not purpose_exists %}
```

Alternatively, if you would like to keep using the original name for the variable, then just negate in the view itself.

```
purpose_is_not_exist = not Purpose.objects.exclude(project=project_code).exists()
```